# plotly with rectangle shading

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'd like to use geom_rect with plotly but if you look at   ggplotly(  g1) you'll see it does not have the geom_rect shading but g1 does. Any idea how to get geom_rect to work with plotly?

thank you.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
rects <- data.frame(xstart = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 12:50:24","GMT"), 
                    xend = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 12:50:26","GMT")
)
mydata = data.frame( time = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:50:23","2018-01-01 12:50:24","2018-01-01 12:50:25","2018-01-01 12:50:26","2018-01-01 12:50:27",
                                         "2018-01-01 12:50:28"),"GMT"), 
                     y = 1:6, z = 101:106, z2= c(6:10,NA) )
g1 =ggplot()+    geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, 
                                             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.1)+
  geom_point( data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = y,text =

                                   paste0( y ," ",z," ",z2)

                                   ))+geom_step(data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = y) )
g1
ggplotly(  g1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure why `geom_rect` is not showing up in your plot, you could get around this by using `geom_polygon`.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
rects <- data.frame(xstart = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 12:50:24", "2018-01-01 12:50:26",
                                          "2018-01-01 12:50:26","2018-01-01 12:50:24"),"GMT"),
                    ystart = c(0, 0, 6, 6))

g1 <- ggplot()+
    geom_polygon(data = rects, aes(x = xstart, y = ystart), alpha = 0.5)+
    geom_point( data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = y))+
    geom_step(data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = y))
ggplotly(g1)
```