# ggplotly not recognizing geom_rect fill from ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to determine how to ensure that the `fill` of a `geom_rect` in `ggplot2` is respected once wrapped in `plotly::ggplotly()`.

Example:

I first create a `data.frame` that contains the values I'll use to generate my plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(provider = rep(c('a','b','c'),2),
           category = c(rep(c('Inpatient'),3),rep(c('Outpatient'),3)),
           revenue = runif(6,100,500),
           background_col = rep(c('red','green','blue'),2)
           )
```

Using just `ggplot` the background panel colors on the `geom_rect` are respected

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=category,y=revenue)) +
              geom_rect(data = dat,aes(fill = background_col),xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf,
                        ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf,alpha = 0.1) +
              geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
              facet_grid(~provider)
```

[image]

But, when I wrap it with `ggplotly`, those background colors disappear.

```
ggplotly(ggplot(dat,aes(x=category,y=revenue)) +
                          geom_rect(data = dat,aes(fill = background_col),xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf,
                                    ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf,alpha = 0.1) +
                          geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
                          facet_grid(~provider))
```

[image]

Any thoughts? I'm not super familiar with all the intricacies of `plotly`, so any insights are helpful!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368587/plotly-with-rectangle-shading. I am guessing it is a bug in plotly

Comment: Yep, good thought. Confirmed bug:https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1559

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to get this automatically, but one workaround that `ggplotly` bug is to use specific numbers in place of -Inf and Inf:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(dat,aes(x=category,y=revenue)) +
           geom_rect(data = dat,aes(fill = background_col),xmin = 0,xmax = 3,
                     ymin = -25,ymax = 475,alpha = 0.1) +
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
           # scale_fill_identity() + # interprets background_col for fill color
           facet_grid(~provider))
```

[image]